# Riemannian Geometry Books

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

Recently I am reading the book Low Dimensional Geometry, From Euclidean Surface to Hyperbolic Knots by the author Francis Bonahon . In this book in chapter 7, define notion of group of transformation, basically a group acts on a metric space and the quotient space again a metric (for details kindly go through the book, page 185). To view of this notion I have some curiosity that, In Riemannian Geometry, Riemannian manifolds are basically are metric spaces(with respect to Riemannian metric), I have read very basic of Riemannian Geometry, any one can see please refer me some good book where  I can study Riemannian Geometry via metric spaces and group of isometries.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to study geometric group theory rather than Riemannian geometry.

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you start with the classic *Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry* by Kobayashi.

Comment: @user10354138, thank you so much for your reference.

Comment: @user10354138 Yeah I want to study geometric group theory but at the same time I want to learn that, is there any notion to geodesically complete metric spaces(Hopf-Rainow theory).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_Structures_for_Riemannian_and_Non-Riemannian_Spaces

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: How much Riemannian geometry do you know? Which RG books have you read?

Comment: Just be warned that Gromov's writings are very hard to read in general -- you are basically required to do a calculation every other sentences or so if you are alert.  There are gentler books out there but they deal with less (and more specific) materials.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have stuidied Lee's smooth manifolds book for now. I guess it is not enough, can please help me how I proceed step by step.

Comment: This is not enough. Consider reading do Carmo " Riemannian geometry."

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you!